# Dynamic Update query in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create an Dynamic UPDATE query for a column listed out in all tables in DB. However, the query is failing with the error  **Code: -942   Message: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-06512: at "MANTAS.P_JRSDCN_TR", line 14.**

Code:-

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE P_JRSDCN_TR
(
out_error_cd out number,        -- Returns 0 if no error; anything else is an error
out_error_msg out varchar2       -- Returns empty string if no error; otherwise the error and trace
)AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
    counter  number(20) :=0;   
CURSOR TAB_COL_CURSOR IS 
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME as TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('KDD_REVIEW') AND COLUMN_NAME='JRSDCN_CD';
 BEGIN  
     FOR TAB_COL_REC  IN TAB_COL_CURSOR
     LOOP

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TAB_COL_REC.TABLE_NAME SET TAB_COL_REC.COLUMN_NAME = P2||SUBSTR(TAB_COL_REC.COLUMN_NAME,3) WHERE SUBSTR(TAB_COL_REC.COLUMN_NAME,1,2)= PL';

counter := counter +SQL%rowcount ;
 If counter >= 50000 then
     counter := 0;
     --commit;
    end if;

-- Done!    
    out_error_cd := 0;
    out_error_msg := '';
    dbms_output.put_line('Turkey Jurisdiction Update completed sucessfully at ' || to_char(sysdate,'MM/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'));
        END Loop;
exception when others then
        rollback;
        out_error_cd := SQLCODE;
        out_error_msg := substr(sqlerrm, 1, 200) || chr(10) || substr(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE, 1, 3896);        
        dbms_output.put_line('  Code: ' || out_error_cd);
        dbms_output.put_line('  Message: ' || out_error_msg);
        dbms_output.put_line('Turkey Jurisdiction Update FAILED at ' || to_char(sysdate,'MM/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'));
 end;
 /
```

Appreciate your help on this procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no table called `TAB_COL_REC.TABLE_NAME`

You probably wanted something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || TAB_COL_REC.TABLE_NAME || ' SET ' || TAB_COL_REC.COLUMN_NAME || ' = P2||SUBSTR(' || TAB_COL_REC.COLUMN_NAME ||',3) WHERE SUBSTR(' || TAB_COL_REC.COLUMN_NAME || ',1,2)= PL';
```

Comment: Hi Cade i modified the query

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10896326

https://support.quest.com/SolutionDetail.aspx?id=SOL48289&pr=Code%20Tester%20for%20Oracle

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/176917/0/

http://www.coderanch.com/t/539059/ORM/databases/ORA-table-view-exist
two causes for the Oracle error code ORA-00942 
The table (or view) really doesn't exist
The database user does not have permission to access (or modify) the table

Comment: Hi Sindhu, Thanks for ur reply.The table exists and the database user is the owner of the table so as i see it,it can modify and I am able to do it outside a procedure.The problem is when i try execute immediate it is not working.Is there any syntax error i am missing..I am new to PL/SQL so I am not sure what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

http://vijvipin.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/plsql-finding-a-column-name-in-all-  tables/

select a.table_name, column_name,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH from all_tab_columns
a,USER_ALL_TABLES u
 where a.TABLE_NAME=u.TABLE_NAME
 and column_name like ‘empid%’
 order by DATA_LENGTH desc;